# Variable in python is not being updated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with a variable in python inside a for, for some reason is not "refreshing" the values, im trying to get the name of some documents that I have in my documents folder, but Im removing the first element and the last one, now my documents name look look like this: 151-document-name-5825, Im creating a script to rename them to document-name but the variable that stores the new name is not saving the name, not sure what Im doing wrong, if you can help me to check I will appreciate it:

```
from pyunpack import Archive
import os
arr = os.listdir()
name = ""
ext = ""
elements = ""
direc = "C:\\Users\\kamr\\Desktop\\Organizar\\"

for i in arr:
  if i.endswith('.pdf'):
    elements = i.split('-')
    numb = len(elements) - 1
    coun = 0
    print(numb)
    name = ""
    for tex in elements:
      if coun > 0 and coun < numb:
        if coun + 1 == numb:
          print(tex)
          name = name + tex
        else:
          print(tex)
          name = name + tex + "-"
    print(name)
    #os.rename(direc + i, direc + name + ".pdf")
```

the "name" variable is always blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never increment the `coun` variable, it stays 0.

So the expression `if coun > 0 ...` never executed, that is why the `name` variable is blank.